# AssertionError with Keras 2.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

The other answers already asked on SO did not answer my question.

I have the following versions:

```
pip list | egrep -i '(keras|tensor)'
Keras                              2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing                1.1.2
tensorboard                        2.4.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit             1.8.0
tensorflow-estimator               2.4.0
tensorflow-gpu                     2.4.1
tensorflow-serving-api             2.4.1
```

Code:

```
def make_generator_model():

  model = tf.keras.Sequential()

  model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

  model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
  logging.info(f"model.output_shape: {model.output_shape}")
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256)  # Note: None is the batch size

  model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  logging.info(f"model.output_shape: {model.output_shape}")
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)

  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

  model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  logging.info(f"model.output_shape: {model.output_shape}")
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 64)
  model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
  model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

  model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
  logging.info(f"model.output_shape: {model.output_shape}")
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 1)

  return model
```

Error:

```
2021-04-08 15:54:32 ERROR Exception caught:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/imgenk", line 348, in main
    args_switch(args, config)
  File "./bin/imgenk", line 297, in args_switch
    return fn(args, config)
  File "./bin/imgenk", line 287, in train_cli
    start_training(args.image_folder)
  File "./bin/imgenk", line 241, in start_training
    generator     = make_generator_model()
  File "./bin/imgenk", line 94, in make_generator_model
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
AssertionError
```

Line 94 is this:

```
  assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
```

In fact the logging before the error:

```
2021-04-08 15:54:32 INFO <BatchDataset shapes: (None, 28, 28, 1), types: tf.float32>
2021-04-08 15:54:32 INFO model.output_shape: (None, 7, 7, 256)
2021-04-08 15:54:32 INFO model.output_shape: (None, 128, 7, 256)
2021-04-08 15:54:32 ERROR Exception caught in main
```

This is really weird. On Python 3.9 this code just works:

```
pip list | egrep -i '(keras|tensor)'
keras-nightly          2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.2
tensorboard            2.4.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.8.0
tensorflow             2.5.0rc0
```

```
2021-04-08 17:59:45 INFO <BatchDataset shapes: (None, 28, 28, 1), types: tf.float32>
2021-04-08 17:59:45 INFO model.output_shape: (None, 7, 7, 256)
2021-04-08 17:59:45 INFO model.output_shape: (None, 7, 7, 128)
2021-04-08 17:59:45 INFO model.output_shape: (None, 14, 14, 64)
2021-04-08 17:59:45 INFO model.output_shape: (None, 28, 28, 1)
```

Does anybody know what could make Keras behave totally differently?

Comment: It looks like your data_format is in `channels_first` mode. Can you check your `~/.keras/keras.json` file to see if `image_data_format` is set? Also, you don't need to install keras if you have tensorflow installed. It's best to not mix both together in your imports (for example, avoid something like `from keras import layers` and `from tensorflow.keras import Model` in the same script).

Comment: It is weird, it is working on different version of Python (I guess because of different version of Tensorflow/Keras).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a different version of Tensorflow + Python combination is causing this. Since this was happening on a AWS instance with a DeepLearning AMI I was able to switch a different environment with different version where the code started to work.